# How to compare all patches in two images in matlab?

Tags: matlab, optimization, image-processing, nearest-neighbor

I have two images, let's say `A` and `B`, sizes of which need not be same. `A` be of dimension 255×255 and `B` be of dimension 100×100. And dimension of a patch is 5×5 for my problem. What I need to do is compare all the patches in `A` to all the patches in `B`.

Every patch will be overlapping with some neighboring patches. To clear this point, first patch in `A` will be `A(1:5,1:5)` (MATLAB notation). Second patch `A(2:6,1:5)` and so on, all the way till `A(251:255,1:5)` at the end of first row, and all the way to `A(251:255,251:255)` for the last patch in `A`.

I have to compare each of these patches against **all** the patches in `B`. As you can see, there are `251*251` patches in `A` and `96*96` patches in `B`. So there are a lot comparisons to be made. And comparison is just Euclidean distance, i.e, I'll just take the difference of two patches and sum the squares. For each patch comparison I'll get a scalar value as result.

I implemented this in MATLAB but it's taking several minutes to execute. So please suggest me the fastest way to implement this. This section is bottlenecking my entire project. The code which I wrote is given below. I'm not an expert clearly so please forgive the mistakes.

```
row = size(A,1);    
col = size(A,2);

row2 = size(B,1);    
col2 = size(B,2);

patch_long = zeros(5,5,(row2-4)*(col2-4));

idx = 1;

for i = 1:row2-4    
    for j = 1:col2-4

        patch_long(:,:,idx) = B(i:i+4,j:j+4);

        idx = idx+1;

    end

end

%// I rearranged 'B' matrix as 3d matrix with each patch arranged like 
%// slide behind one by one

parfor m = 1:row-4    
    for n = 1:col-4

        temp1 = bsxfun(@minus,(A(m:m+4,n:n+4)),patch_long);
        temp2 = sum(sum(temp1.^2));

        count = sum(temp2 <=threshold);

        if count > 1 
            % Do xyzend
        end

    end
end

%// count counts how many patches in 'B' are close to a particular patch in 'A'.
```

Comment: You actually did a good vectorization. Seems like this cannot be significantly improved. Consider algorithmic improvements. Like, do you really need to compare ALL patches to ALL?

Comment: Do you happen to have a double-precision capable GPU? And what version of MATLAB do you have?

Comment: I don't know about GPU. My matlab version is 2012b.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis : do you mean I should first write 'for cols' and then 'for rows' when looping?

Comment: What do you see if you type `gpuDevice` in the command prompt?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis I'm using matlab in ubuntu. When I typed gpuDevice it's showing an error.

"There is a problem with the CUDA driver associated with this GPU device. 
Caused by:
    The CUDA driver could not be loaded. The library name used was 'libcuda.so.1'. The error was:
    libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Comment: Yeah, that just means you don't have a CUDA-capable graphics device (NVIDIA card with DP arithmetic), so this is not an option.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`im2col`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) to extract all patches

```
pA = im2col( A, [5 5], 'sliding' );
pB = im2bol( B, [5 5], 'sliding' );
% compute squared difference
D = sum( bsxfun( @minus, permute( pA, [2 3 1] ), permute( pB, [3 2 1] ) ).^2, 3 );
```

---

By the way, if you do not need ALL the distances and willing to compromise for an approximation for the `k` nearest neighbors, you might find [PatchMatch](http://gfx.cs.princeton.edu/pubs/Barnes_2009_PAR/index.php) very useful:
This is an approximate `k`-nearest neighbors algorithm tailored for image patches. It is very efficient in terms of memory (space) usage and very fast.

Comment: Looking at my implementation of `im2col` (I'm on R2010b now), it doesn't do anything different from what the OP already did, except use a lot more memory...Except shortening the code, I cannot produce any significant speed difference. Perhaps the implementation changed in later versions; can you verify a speedup with your (newer) version?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis I do not have access to newer version(s). sorry.

Comment: I need to find at most 10 patches which satisfy the threshold criteria. I mean for a patch, if no patch is there with distance less than threshold, it is ok. But if there are more than 10 patches then I'll choose the closest 10 patches. But how can I find 10-nearest neighbors without comparing all the patches? 

One more constraint is that, threshold is a matrix of size 251x251( as per the example). It has the threshold corresponding to every patch in A.

Comment: @akhilc, in that case, you only need the 10 nearest neighbors (NN) of each patch: if they are closer than the threshold; you use all of them, if not you only use part of them. To get EXACTLY the 10 NN you do need to extensively compare to all the others. BUT, if you are willing to make some approximations, you can get the (approximate) 10 NN **much** faster. Take a look at PatchMatch!

Comment: @Shai, I'm not sure how the approximate NN will affect the whole project. Let me give it a try. thank you.

Comment: @akhilc - if you are experimenting with PatchMatch, can you please post some information regarding your results: at least in terms of run time. How fast is PatchMatch compared to brute-force comparison of patches.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, PatchMatch is a break-early version of the brute force approach. That means, it's still O(N²) worst case (none but the very last patches are below the threshold). Is this correct?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis In theory you are correct, PatchMatch will run its iterations and reach O(N^2) complexity. But the statistical analysis of the algorithm allows a VERY early termination of the iterative process at a very low approximation cost. In practice (If I recall correctly) its complexity is only O(N) at a very small approximation error.

Comment: @Shai, I downloaded Patchmatch but I'm not sure how to run it. There are lot of files inside it. There's no 'readme.txt' in it either. And I tried reading the associated paper but it's not that easy. So I'm not really sure if I can truly make this useful. Thank you though.

Comment: @akhilc I see a `readme.txt` file in the version I downloaded from [here](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/gfx/pubs/Barnes_2009_PAR/patchmatch-2.0.zip).

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Mikhail, you actually did a terrific job. There is really not all that much you can improve.

There are only a few minor things you can do:

1. swap the processing order of the matrices
2. swap the loop order

Because `A` is smaller than `B`, swapping the processing order will cause `bsxfun` to do more of the heavy lifting. Since that is "closer to the silicon" than a JIT'ed MATLAB loop, this will be beneficial.

Doing a simple `tic...toc` test with `A = rand(255)` and `B = rand(10)` (I don't have all day! :) gives

```
Elapsed time is 3.460361 seconds.  %// original processing order
Elapsed time is 1.629848 seconds.  %// inverted processing order
```

For your case, the difference will be less of course, but this could be significant.

Swapping the loop order (loop over rows in the inner loop, columns on the outer loop) works because MATLAB stores data in column-major order. Swapping the order then means the pointer offset calculation can be re-used in the inner loop, thus requiring less operations. Normally, this can make up to ~30% difference, however, recent versions of MATLAB have greatly improved upon this (still not sure how), and you don't use 1 column, but 5...so this will probably not be as significant.

Doing the same test, with the different loop order, gives:

```
Elapsed time is 3.462599 seconds. %// original loop order
Elapsed time is 3.272909 seconds. %// inverted loop order
```

Combining everything:

```
Elapsed time is 1.571496 seconds. %// Both optimizations implemented
```

My code:

```
%// random data for testing
A = rand(255);
B = rand(10);
threshold = rand;

[rowA, colA] = size(A);
[rowB, colB] = size(B);

patch_long = zeros(5,5, (rowA-4)*(colA-4));

tic

%// re-arrange A into 3D array of 5×5 patches 
idx = 1;
for jj = 1:colA-4     
    c = jj:jj+4;      %// re-use column indices
    for ii = 1:rowA-4 %// inner loop is over the rows

        patch_long(:,:,idx) = A(ii:ii+4, c);        
        idx = idx+1;

    end

end

%// The heavy lifting
for n = 1:colB-4     %// let bsxfun do more work; loop over smallest array here
    c = n:n+4;       %// re-use column indices
    for m = 1:rowB-4 %// inner loop is over the rows

        temp1 = bsxfun(@minus, B(m:m+4, c), patch_long);
        count = sum( sum(temp1.^2) <= threshold );

    end
end

toc
```

Note that I didn't use `parfor`, just to keep everything copy-pastable for everyone. Using `parfor` on the *real* problem gives me

```
Elapsed time is 387.802798 seconds. %// original version, but without parfor
Elapsed time is 362.991760 seconds. %// both optimizations, WITH parfor
```

but I think this is mostly because my work PC is pretty bad (AMD-A6 3650 APU).

Comment: thank you very much. let me try this and get back to you later.

Comment: I ran your optimized code for A(255,255) and B(50,50). It took 30 sec for 'row first then column method' and 29.5 for your suggested looping method. I think for bigger image this could save me considerable amount of time. 


 Your second suggestion though is a bit difficult for me to incorporate. I mean using looping over 'B'. It's because 'threshold' is actually a matrix. For every patch in 'A' there is a unique threshold value. So 'threshold' is a 251x251 matrix and the comparison is actually "sum(sum(temp1.^2 <= threshold(m,n)". That is when I'm iterating over 'A' it's easier to write this.

Comment: @akhilc: `(y-x)² < z` for matrices `x`, `y` and `c` can be written as `(y<x & y>x-sqrt(z)) | (y>=x & y<x+sqrt(z))`. You can thus pre-compute `A-sqrt(c)` and `A+sqrt(c)` in the `A` loop, and use those values in the `B`-loop. However, these comparisons will have to be done with ***FOUR*** calls to `bsxfun`, so I'm not sure this will be effective...But hey, it's worth a try.